# Issue with libpq.so.5 and PQencryptPasswordConn version RHPG_10 on Fedora30

Tags: python, fedora, libpq, libpqxx, fedora-commons

I am trying to run my python script but I am getting below error. I tried to install and uninstall psycopg2  in different ways but is not working. My postgres version is 9.6 and my psycopg2 version is 2.8.2. Anyone had the same issue? Thanks in advance.

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "server.py", line 89, in <module>
        cfg = Config(application, WSGI_PATH_PREFIX)
      File "server.py", line 60, in __init__
        self.mgrs = managers.register_managers(self.app)
      File "api/managers_fourwalls.py", line 31, in register_managers
        return Managers(app)
      File "api/managers_fourwalls.py", line 41, in __init__
        self.FourwallsEngine = four_walls({"posgres_db": self.DataManager.pg_connection_string})
      File "api/engine/four_walls_engine.py", line 14, in __init__
        self.engine = create_engine(self.db_string)
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/__init__.py", line 387, in create_engine
        return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 80, in create
        dbapi = dialect_cls.dbapi(**dbapi_args)
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/psycopg2.py", line 554, in dbapi
        import psycopg2
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
        from psycopg2._psycopg import (                     # noqa
    ImportError: /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so: symbol PQencryptPasswordConn version RHPG_10 not defined in file libpq.so.5 with link time reference
```

Answer (score 7):

I solved the issue installing the binary stand alone:

```
pip install psycopg2-binary
```